# What does the 'D' stand for in all the names?

Tags: one-piece

There are a lot of characters with the middle initial "D".  Is this an indication of something, or do they really all just have middle initials of the letter D?  If they are initials, do we know what they stand for?

Examples of names:

> Monkey D. Luffy
>   Monkey D. Dragon
>   Portgas D. Ace
>   Monkey D. Garp
>   Gol D. Roger

Comment: And don't just forget Marshall D. Teach

Comment: also Trafalgar D. Law

Comment: And with [Jaguar D. Saul](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jaguar_D._Saul), [Portgas D. Rouge](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Portgas_D._Rouge), and [Marshall D. Teach](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Marshall_D._Teach). I don't think `D` has any other meaning but that letter itself since it's inherited by the god's natural enemies.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Update

We start to see the meaning behind the D. In the episode 703 of the Anime...

> ...Corazon talks to Trafalgar D. Law, telling him how young kids in Marie Jois are instructed to see D. as a sort of boogeyman:
>
>  *"Badly behaving children will be eaten by the D."*
>
>  He continues saying that in some parts of the world, the Family of D. is known as 神の天敵 (kami no ten teki), translated "God's natural enemy".
>
>  He also states that "God" in this instance is used to refer to the Celestial Dragons.

---

It hasn't been revealed yet I think.

> The initial was first pointed out in Oda's [SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS) questions and answers corner, he was also asked what the D in Luffy's name stood for. Oda just replied to read it as a D for now and that he would reveal the truth behind it in time.

You can read more in the [Will of the D.](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_D.) wiki.

Comment: Celestial Dragons (天竜人) is to gods as D People (神の天敵) is to demons. I'd like to add that "Old Roger" is a nickname for the Devil (Gol D. Roger), and notice that Luffy used "Lucy" (from Lucifer) as his codename in the arena. So yes, D has something to do with the Devil and demons. Other words that start with the letter "d" may also have something to do with them, like destiny, death, destruction, dream, etc. It could also have a connection to the moon, as a half-moon looks like a D shape, and the moon phases are shown very often.