# What are the similarities between Gol D. Roger and Monkey D. Luffy? Are they related by blood? What are their relatives' ages?

Tags: one-piece

This question is regarding **One Piece**.

I have **three** questions to ask. Since they are interrelated, I'm asking them as a single question on this site.

---

As I was reading about the prominent people in the One Piece universe, I came across [**Roger's page**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gol_D._Roger#Personality). It has been mentioned there and in many other places that Luffy is quite similar to Roger in character. Theories on some [**forums**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Luffy_%26_Roger) have gone so far as to state that Luffy is Roger's reincarnation. So,

**1. Could anyone list ALL the similarities between Roger and Luffy?**

This question might seem too broad and ambiguous, but when I say similarity, what I'm mostly referring to is

- A common something that the two share
- An instance where Luffy says or does something that reminds someone of Roger
- Parallel life events

I came across [**this**](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ymbus) video and [**this**](http://forums.saiyanisland.com/showthread.php?t=9486) link that cover a few of them. I'll post the relevant ones here.

- ***A common something that the two share:***

  - [**Will of D**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_D.)

    Gol **D.** Roger
    Monkey **D.** Luffy
  - [**The Straw Hat**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Straw_Hat#Monkey_D._Luffy)

    > In the manga and anime One Piece, Monkey D. Luffy's straw hat is the
    >   main symbol of the entire series and is the origin of his nickname
    >   "Straw Hat Luffy."
    >
    > Much later, during the Straw Hat Pirates' departure for Fishman
    >   Island, it was revealed by Silvers Rayleigh that this straw hat
    >   originally belonged to Gol D. Roger.
  - [**Both can hear Sea Kings**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sea_King#Poseidon)

    > Besides the Mermaid of legend, the only other people who seem to be
    >   able to hear the Sea King have been Monkey D. Luffy and Gol D. Roger.
    >   The latter was said to be able to "hear the voice of all things".
  - **Both their first mates have a scar over one eye**

    This is probably pure coincidence, or not.

    [**Silvers Rayleigh**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Silvers_Rayleigh?file=Rayleigh_Wax.png)
    [**Roronoa Zoro**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Roronoa_Zoro/Gallery?file=Zoro_Outfit_Punk_Hazard.png)
  - **Both are from** [**East Blue**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/East_Blue#Birth_and_Death_of_the_Pirate_King)**(?)**

    > Loguetown, the city in the East Blue located closest to the Grand
    >   Line, was the birthplace of the late Pirate King, Gol D. Roger.
    >
    > Dawn Island: home island of Monkey D. Luffy, where he was raised in
    >   the peaceful Foosha Village and where he trained on Mt. Colubo.

    It is mentioned that Dawn Island is Luffy's home island, but is it mentioned anywhere that he was born there?
  - [**The Supernova title**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Supernova)**(?)**

    Luffy is a Super Rookie, but was Roger one?
    In the video link above, Brook says

    > Gold Roger? There might have been a rookie by that name, or maybe
    >   there wasn't...

    Is there any solid proof that Roger was a rookie?
- ***Instances where Luffy says or does something that reminds someone of Roger:***

  - [**Luffy's smile when Buggy tries to execute him reminds Smoker of Roger**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Smoker#Monkey_D._Luffy)

    > Smoker saw the smile Luffy gave off to mirror that of Gol D. Roger's
    >   twenty-two years ago, and considered Luffy to be a potential danger to
    >   the world.
  - [**Luffy's answer to Rayleigh when he's asked how he intends to conquer the Grand Line**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Silvers_Rayleigh#Sabaody_Archipelago_Arc)

    > Luffy replied that he does not really intend to conquer it, but that
    >   the person with the most freedom in the ocean would be the Pirate
    >   King. This brought a smile to Rayleigh's and Shakky's faces, seeing
    >   the unmistakable likeness to Roger in Luffy just as Shanks saw.
  - [**Luffy's words to Raoul that he will be the next Pirate King**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Raoul#Loguetown_Arc)

    > He was deeply shocked at hearing Luffy saying he will be the next
    >   Pirate King and noted that the young boy was similar to Roger in his
    >   presence.
- ***Parallel life events***:

  - **The first person that Roger and Luffy ask to join them on their journey refuses to do so, but eventually accept the offer. Coincidentally, that person also become their crew's first mate.**

    [**Rayleigh**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Silvers_Rayleigh#Past)**:**

    > At first Rayleigh declined, but some time later, he formed a bond with
    >   Roger and became his first mate.

    [**Zoro**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Roronoa_Zoro/History#Meeting_Luffy)**:**

    > Luffy asked Zoro to join him but he flatly refused to become a pirate. Refusing to die, Zoro accepted Luffy's invitation and revealed his unique fighting style.

Could anyone list other similarities and when doing so, state where the similarity is mentioned: manga, anime or both? Also, could you prove or disprove the East Blue and Supernova cases?

---

The similarities could just mean that the two are extremely like-minded individuals or it could mean that they are related.

While in prison, Roger asks Garp to take care of his unborn son, Ace. From this, it is obvious that there's a strong bond between the two. Is the relationship based only on deep trust or are the Gol and Monkey families related? Basically,

**2. Is Roger related by blood to Garp, and in turn, to Luffy?**

A search on the web doesn't yield much, but from threads like [**this**](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/324oi4/monkey_d_garp_and_gol_d_roger_relation_relatives/), [**this**](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/1hsk27/one_piece_monkey_d_garp_is_the_father_of_gol_d/) and [**this**](http://www.arlongpark.net/showthread.php?t=28925), a few likely possibilities(barring all supernatural theories) are:

- Roger is Garp's brother or brother-in-law.
- Roger is Garp's son or son-in-law.

If the relationship had been revealed explicitly, Wikipedia and Wikia would have the answer. Since it's not, has it ever been implied indirectly, anywhere in the manga/anime that Roger and Luffy are blood relatives?

---

Since the answer to the above question might possibly be 'no' (at least for the time being), the ages of the people involved will be helpful pointers to accord with or negate theories about how Roger and Luffy could be related, to form one's own theories, or to refute the very idea that they are related. As of now, only [**Luffy's and Ace's ages**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/User:Yatanogarasu/Age,_Height,_and_Birthday) are known, which leads to my third question,

**3. What are Garp's, Roger's, Rouge's and Dragon's ages?**

As with the second question, there's no answer in any online encyclopedia.

But some statements found on the Wikia pages are:

> - Thirty years ago, he* fought Chinjao and earned his hatred after denting his pointy head and robbing him of the means to acquire
>     a certain treasure.
> - It would seem that he** had been around for some time, considering that Brook refers to him as a rookie, more than 50 years
>     before the current storyline.
> - Twelve years before the current storyline, Dragon returned to his home in the Goa Kingdom and witnessed the burning of the Gray
>     Terminal.

*Garp
**Roger

Have there been other time related statements in the manga/anime in relation to these four people that could be used to make a rough estimate of their ages?

---

My apologies regarding the lengthy question.I put in all the facts that I know so that if anyone answers this question, the things I already know will be skipped. A hardcore One Piece fan will probably be able to answer. Also, my knowledge about the series is mostly limited to the Wikia and Wikipedia pages.

Comment: I agree that the first and the second question are related, but you might want to post the third question as a separate one, because I don't see the relation between it and the other two.

Comment: Since I don't know if Roger and Luffy are blood related or not, I wanna know their approx. ages so that I can form my own fan theories about them :D Thank you for mentioning it, I'll change it into a separate question if others feel the same.Meanwhile, I'll edit the question so that it makes more sense :)

Comment: Related Question: [what does the D stand for in all the names](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/724/1458)

Comment: @Dimitri mx: Thanks, but how are they related? I don't wanna know what the D stands for..

Comment: Luffy is Roger reincarnation :v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** You answered question yourself.

**2.** No, they are not related. As Garp hunts Roger across the sea and visits him in prison as an old rival and not as a relative, it is safe to say that they are not relatives. I am not sure when but I think when Aces story is told, it says that Roger asked Garp - because of the 'D.' - to save his son (Ace) from the marine trying to kill all relatives that may have Roger's talent to make trouble.

This again shows that there is no known close relative alive. They are however related in some way because the 'D.' is passed from one generation to the other and it is likely that there were one family or (less likely) people with the 'D.'. That is the closest we can be sure and the closest that is likely if we want to speculate - what is not the purpose of this site.

**3.**
The Ages of the ones carrying the 'Will of D.' can be found [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_D.#Carriers.27_Profile):

> Luffy: 19
>  Dragon: unkknown
>  Garp: 78
>  Roger: would be 77
>   now
>  Rouge: unknown
>  Ace: would be 22 now

Comment: My long post elaborating the first two questions was meant to make people not repeat the same answers again. If you're really thorough with the One Piece universe and can confirm that there are no other additions at all, please inform me, I will select your answer and close this question. The answers cannot be found in websites AFAIK, only a person who knows the story perfectly can answer this I think.

Comment: A fandom of this scale can never be fully explored even when we hit the end of the story we can't say for sure that we have all similarities. But I edited my answer to include something to #2.

Answer (score -1):

Could Roger and Luffy's mother be siblings. Luffy's mother is likely deceased. She may have had that similar disease that Roger died from. If they are related, it would explain why Dragon was present for Roger's death. It would explain why Luffy has alot of similarities with Roger why Garp had a personal relationship with Roger, why Raleigh felt a connection with Luffy. That would make Luffy and Ace cousins or brothers using Hyuga Clan logic.

Comment: theories and speculation are not proper answers, OP is asking for facts stated in the series that could back-up said claims.